# "Allow Delete Only If" Permission

Tags: permissions, sharing-rule, owd

Disclaimer: Permission settings newbie here.

In my org, there are 3 departments. I've set up a role hierarchy with three branches where each head of department (HOD) is at the top. Underneath is another role to hold the subordinate users for each department.

Requirement 1: All users are allowed to view lead records from the other departments, but can edit/delete their own records only.

Requirement 2: The HOD is allowed to edit/delete all leads under their respective departments only.

Should I set the OWD for Lead to public read-only, and then create a read/write sharing rule for each department? How do I allow the HOD to delete all records under his/her respective department only, or will this be taken care of already by both the role hierarchy and read/write sharing rule? Anything that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set the Org Wide Defaults to Public Read Only. This gives all users the ability to view all leads (but not edit). By placing the HOD above the users in the role hierarchy, they automatically inherit Owner access (Read/Edit/Delete) permissions. There is no need for a sharing rule or other settings.

Comment: thanks sfdcfox, i'll give it a try!